# search and replace from a output to a matching pattern inside a file

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, awk, sed

Am trying to write AWS Cloud formation scripts for security groups, the process is too very repeatable am trying for few hacks to automate it

I have CSV output from the following calls to `awk` and `sed`:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { OFS=",";print $2, $3, $4, $5 }' para.csv | sed -n 1p
```

Output:

```
10.0.0.0/8,tcp,53,53
```

I need to map this output to a file which has the following

```
"ingress5": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupId": {
          "Ref": "sginformatica"
        },
        "IpProtocol": "",
        "FromPort": "",
        "ToPort": "",
        "CidrIp": ""
      }
},
```

ie from the output of the command `IpProtocol` should be mapped to `tcp`.

`FromPort` should be mapped `53` (column 3 or field 3 in the output)

`ToPort` should be mapped `53` (column 4 or field 4 in the output)

`CidrIp` should be mapped to `10.0.0.0/8` ( field 1 of the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r CidrIp IpProtocol FromPort ToPort; do
cat << EOF
"ingress5": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupId": {
          "Ref": "sginformatica"
        },
        "IpProtocol": "$IpProtocol",
        "FromPort": "$FromPort",
        "ToPort": "$ToPort",
        "CidrIp": "$CidrIp"
      }
},
EOF
done < file
```

With this file:

```
10.0.0.0/8,tcp,53,53
```

Output:

```
"ingress5": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupId": {
          "Ref": "sginformatica"
        },
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "53",
        "ToPort": "53",
        "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8"
      }
},
```

---

Or without a file:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { OFS=",";print $2, $3, $4, $5 }' para.csv | sed -n 1p | while ...; do ...; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Install and use flexible command-line JSON processor - [***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Let's say we have `ingress.json` file with contents:

```
{
    "ingress5": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupId": {
          "Ref": "sginformatica"
        },
        "IpProtocol": "",
        "FromPort": "",
        "ToPort": "",
        "CidrIp": ""
      }
    }
}
```

At first, we'll adjust the crucial input string to look as a valid json string:

```
v="["$(awk -F, '{ OFS=",";print "\042"$2"\042", "\042"$3"\042", $4, $5 }' para.csv | sed -n 1p)"]"
echo $v
["10.0.0.0/8","tcp",53,53]
```

The next step is modifying the needed attribute values using ***jq*** command:

```
jq --argjson v "$v" '.ingress5.Properties.IpProtocol = $v[1] | .ingress5.Properties.FromPort = $v[2] 
  | .ingress5.Properties.ToPort = $v[3] | .ingress5.Properties.CidrIp = $v[0]' ingress.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "ingress5": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
    "Properties": {
      "GroupId": {
        "Ref": "sginformatica"
      },
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "FromPort": 53,
      "ToPort": 53,
      "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: will try the jq one

Comment: @SaravananD, so try